# PHP Multidimensional Array Iterating From Text File

Tags: php, string, file, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a text file named **C.txt**. The contens of the text file goes as following:

> Name,      BPrice, SPrice, Display
>   Nokia 520,  20000,  21000,  1
>   Xiaomi123,  15000,  17000,  0
>   Xiaomi Redmi,   30000,  32000,  1

I have accessed the file using the following code:

```
<?php

    $file = fopen("C.txt", "r");
    while(!feof($file)){
        $content = fgets($file);
        $products[] = $content;
    }

    var_dump($products);

?>
```

`var_dump($products)` gives output:

> array(4) { [0]=> string(33) "Name, BPrice, SPrice, Display " [1]=> string(29) "Nokia 520,  20000,  21000,  1   " [2]=> string(29) "Xiaomi123,  15000,  17000,  0   " [3]=> string(30) "Xiaomi Redmi,   30000,  32000,  1   " }

What I wanted to do, is to separate the *Name*, *BPrice*, *SPrice* and *Display* columns and their values using `explode()` method. So, I tried the following:

```
<?php

        for($i=1; $i<count($products); $i++){

              $contents[] = explode(",", $products[$i]);

        }

        var_dump($contents);

?>
```

`var_dump($contents)` yields:

> array(3) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "Nokia 520" [1]=> string(6) "  20000" [2]=> string(6) "    21000" [3]=> string(5) "    1   " } [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "Xiaomi123" [1]=> string(6) "  15000" [2]=> string(6) "    17000" [3]=> string(5) "    0   " } [2]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(12) "Xiaomi Redmi" [1]=> string(6) "  30000" [2]=> string(6) "    32000" [3]=> string(3) "    1   " } }

**NOTE: I wanted to access only the values of the columns and not the headers, hence `for($i=1; $i<count($products); $i++)`**

Now here is where I'm facing the problem. How do I access this two dimensional array `$contents`?
I have tried the `foreach loop` as following:

```
foreach ($contents as $key => $value) {
    echo $value[$key];
}
```

But that results in:

> Nokia 520  15000   32000

I cannot seem to figure out **why it is not printing the rest of the two rows!** Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: take a look at `fgetcsv` ~ http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the `echo $value[$key];`.
The $key variable in this context holds the key of current `$contents` array member, while you are using it to access the value of the inside array, the product data.

Since this is a multi-dimensional array, you will need multiple loops to print it all out. So if you'd like to do that, it would work like this:

```
foreach ($contents as $productValues) {
    foreach ($productValues as $productValue) {
        echo $productValue;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function for parsing cvs files into an associative array with the column names as array keys:

```
function csvArray($file) {
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));
    array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {
      $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
    });
    array_shift($csv);
return $csv;
}
```

Then result of

```
$phones = csvArray('c.txt');
print_r($phones);
```

Is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Nokia 520
            [ BPrice] =>  20000
            [ SPrice] =>  21000
            [ Display] =>  1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Xiaomi123
            [ BPrice] =>  15000
            [ SPrice] =>  17000
            [ Display] =>  0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Xiaomi Redmi
            [ BPrice] =>  30000
            [ SPrice] =>  32000
            [ Display] =>  1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array in more readable terms looks like this

```
[["Nokia 520", "20000", "21000", "1"], 
 ["Xiaomi123", "15000", "17000", "0"], 
 ["Xiaomi Redmi", "30000", "32000", "1"]]
```

This means that in your `foreach`, the **value** of your first key is

```
["Nokia 520", "20000", "21000", "1"]
```

The reason you are only getting those values is that you are doing

```
echo $value[$key];
```

So essentially you are returning positions `0` `1` and `2` of `["Nokia 520", "20000", "21000", "1"]`, which are the values `Nokia 520`, `20000` and `21000`

To get the values you actually want, you need to perform two foreach loops

```
foreach ($arr as $keys) {
    foreach($keys as $value) {
        echo "{$value} ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```